# Why is HttpContext.Current sometimes null when using ASP.NET ReportViewer?

Tags: c#, asp.net, reportviewer, httpcontext, reportviewer2008

In our ASP.NET Web Application, we have a service with a life-time/scope that can described as "instance per request" i.e. the instance is stored in the `HttpContext.Current.Items` collection.

We have had this intermittent issue where the `HttpContext.Current` property is `null` during calls from the ASP.NET `ReportViewer` control. Sometimes it is `null`, sometimes it is not. The behaviour can be different on the staging website versus a dev machine, and even varies between different dev machines.

This will cause a report which would like to use our service to throw an exception.

Why is the `HttpContext.Current` property `null`?

Why is it intermittent?

Comment: Did anyone find an answer to this? I find it is always null, meaning I cannot use HttpContext.Current.ResolveUrl. I also cannot use System.Web.VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute as that is throwing a type initialization exception.

Comment: Hi. You may be suffering from the same problem where you are accessing HttpContext.Current from a thread other than the main HTTP request servicing thread. Have a look at the blog post I linked to.

Comment: Thanks. I see that blog post makes a very important point that I have been working towards which is that my report object classes should not be dependant on ASP.Net machinery, hence we cannot access HttpContext.Current but that is OK because we should not be trying to. Otherwise I cannot use my reports in web forms apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source of the problem seems to be that the Report Viewer sometimes uses Thread Pool threads to retrieve data for DataSets defined in the report. Thread Pool threads cannot access the `HttpContext.Current` instance of the thread servicing the HTTP request ([more information in this blog post](http://odetocode.com/articles/112.aspx)).

The reports in my scenario had a number of DataSets in the report definition which each corresponded to an `ObjectDataSource` defined on the page. After extensive debugging I found that the report would retrieve the data for the first DataSet declared in the report definition on the same thread that services the HTTP request. Any subsequent DataSets would *either* be retrieved on the main HTTP request thread *or* a Thread Pool thread. These subsequent DataSets would then intermittently throw exceptions saying that `HttpContext.Current` was null.

There does not seem to be any way to predict or control what thread a DataSet will be retrieved on after the first one.